# access the CI session in a pre controller codeigniter hook

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, internationalization, multilingual

I am using a pre controller hook to detect and set the site language from the session/cookie/browser lang detection.. something like this answer:
[Codeigniter language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222558/codeigniter-language)

I am also using the famous Tank Auth library to manage users and I am using the codeigniter Session class to store and manage the users sessions upon log in. Each user can specify the interface language he wants and store it in the database for future log ins. The lang info is copied from the DB to the session on every log in.

The problem is: I can't check the user session from inside the hook. How would I know (in case of logged in users) if his session has the lang info or not?

I am not sure if the hook approach is the best one in case of handling logged in users sessions. Let me know please if I can have a better approach.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using a *post_controller_constructor* hook instead of *pre_controller*. In that hook, the session is accessible. So I am setting the detected lang in the CI session AND i am loading the language file accordingly.

I am not sure if this is the best approach, but it works fine if you are not using the lang library in any controller constructor.

Comment: I had that same problem. I tried to use post_controller_constructor but ran into issues because I was autoloading a language file which must loaded before post_controller_constructor. My fix was to load my "auto loaded" language files at the bottom of my hook

Comment: if you use "post_controller_constructor" hook and set language of CI there, autoloaded language files will not be changed to that language, because they are already loaded before your hook. Thomas fix is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

use a post_controller_constructor hock. It is called after the controller constructor and before the controller method. It should do the trick for you. For me it did

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution is to try loading the session library in a CI instance from your pre-controller hook.

```
$CI = &get_instance();   
$CI->load->library('session');
// --- Then ---
$var = $CI->session->userdata('$the_variable_youre_checking');
```

Comment: the function get_instance() doesn't work in a pre controller hook.. it is not loaded in CI yet