# Compare cookie on site load

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am using Code Igniter and I am implementing a remember user functionality.

Basically, from another stack overflow post, I implemented this the right way where I generate a random string for that user, save it in the database AND in a cookie. On site load, I check for that cookie, if that cookie is found I check it in the database. If it is found in the database then recrease the session for that user.

The problem I am having is when I load the site. I am getting the value of the cookie and I am also getting the correct response from the AJAX call. However, I have to click on a link  in order for the session to get recreated (such as menu is displayed for logged in user and so on).

I am thinking that I am recreating the session AFTER the index method of the main controller is called. How can I get around this in Code Igniter? Where can I put this code which preferably gets run first thing on every page? As for instance I also want to recreate the session if the user enters the site's contact us page instead of the home page.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter allows the developer to create hooks which are called at different moments before the controller method is called.

Here is a short description of how to use hooks:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

If you want to access the session, I would recommend to use a `post_controller_constructor` hook, which is called after the controller constructor is executed, but before the action method is called. ( [access the CI session in a pre controller codeigniter hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674166/access-the-ci-session-in-a-pre-controller-codeigniter-hook) )

Comment: Thanks for this I managed to get it to work. However the cookie's value is still not being read on site load but after I click on some other link. Any ideas why this might be happening? If a cookie is stored on the client's machine, PHP should be able to pick it up on site load if I am not mistaken.

Comment: It should load the available cookies on site load. You could use `Firebug` or some tool to check the headers and try to find more information. Also, if you are using CI cookie library, you might try to make a test using regular PHP functions and see if that works.

Comment: Never mind it worked flawlessly. The problem was that I am using my no-ip address to access the site from anywhere but it is still on localhost. Thus when accessing it via localhost, it wouldn't work. As soon as I clicked on a link I got redirected to the actual no-ip URL where the cookie existed. Basically, if I do not use localhost, it works flawlessly. Kudos!