# Get character from text file php

Tags: php, regex, explode

I am trying to read character of a text file.

```
$lang['content.home'] = 'Home';
$lang['content.about_us'] = 'About Us';
$lang['content.team'] = 'team';
```

how to get just character

**content.home** and **Home**

and

**content.about_us** and **About Us**

and

**content.team** and **team**

i try using explode('\'', $data) but not work well

Comment: In what format do you want the result?

Comment: array(1)
(
    [0] => string(5) "content.home"
    [1] => string(5) "Home"
)

Comment: And you don't want to include_once() it why exactly?

Comment: i think to explode to use form input field to change language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by `foreach` you can get  `$lang` `key` and `value`

```
 $lang['content.home'] = 'Home';
 $lang['content.about_us'] = 'About Us';
 $lang['content.team'] = 'team';
 foreach($lang as $key=>$value){
    echo $key."<br>\n";
    echo $value;
 }
```

Comment: if i echo $value just show HomeAbout UsTeam how to get content.home or content.about_us or content.team?

Comment: i have probleme i get $lang['content.home] = 'Home'; from file text $lang = read_file(APPPATH . "language/english/content_lang.php"); and $lang can't use to foreach please help

Comment: you must use `require_once` instead of  `read_file` like `require_once("language/english/content_lang.php");` before `foreach`

Comment: in lang better to use array directly for echo like `echo  $lang['content.team'];` output is `team`

Comment: if in controller 
$data['lang'] = read_file(APPPATH . "language/bahasa/english.php");
        $this->load->view('test', $data);
how to show in view?

Comment: see this pages for codeigniter  language http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222558/codeigniter-language